# Python 2.5: IO module

Tags: python, io

I would like to use Python's [IO](http://docs.python.org/library/io.html) module. It was only introduced in Python 2.6 and I'm stuck with 2.5 for now. Is the particular IO module provided with Python 2.6 available as a separate module that can be used with 2.5?

Comment: The module was actually introduced in Python 3.x and then backported for 2.6.  I'm pretty sure there is no 2.5 version.  What feature in particular would you like to use?

Comment: I'm using StringIO to make some XML data available for etree to parse, as in `tree = etree.parse(io.StringIO(myXml))`

Comment: Use cStringIO. Pure-Python `io` is slow as hell anyway, and C version will probably be hell to backport.

Comment: Brilliant—cStringIO works like a charm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IO module has undergone a number of significant revisions since it was introduced.  For Python 2.7 and 3.1, it was supplemented by a much faster C version and many bugs have been fixed.  As far as I know, no one has attempted to back port the current version to 2.5.  Unfortunately, your best bet is to use 2.7.

Comment: Looks like the Python 2.6 io.py is pure, after importing _fileio.c . Is old but may be a good starting point